# Ruby - write at seeked position

Tags: ruby

Goal is to replace 'byebye' with 'Hello '

```
# START: file.txt contains string "byebye World!"
fd = File.open('file.txt', 'a')

fd.seek(0, IO::SEEK_SET)
fd.puts 'Hello '
fd.close
# END: file.txt contains two lines "byebye World " and "Hello "
```

I understand what exists other excellent ( and working:) ) ways to achieve it, but why that code don't write on right position?

Comment: puts adds a newline use print

Comment: in 'a/a+' mode write always performs at the end of file, to write at seeked position 'r+' mode needed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514448/writing-to-the-middle-of-a-file-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding w+, you may want r+ as the modestring, here's what w+ does.

```
w+
Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length or creates a new file for reading and writing.
```

truncate existing file to zero length is eating your string.